# How to show always the pop-up at the point in a cloud graph?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In below picture you can see the pop-up which appears on hover. I want that it always appears and on the other point too.

[image: graph]

Comment: Hi @Kirill Kirs, That is a Highcharts tooltip: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please do not link to images, as the link may die over time. Also write please your question and show us what you have already tried? Please read this page to see how to properly ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek it can help me. I want them still to show up without the mouse hover

Comment: On basic line, I would like to show up/print the value of every points, is-it possible ?

Comment: do you want all tool tips without mouse hover? or did you trying something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/dpn38e5b/

Comment: Yes, thanks you! It is exactly what I want to do. The goal is every tool tips stay posted all the time without putting the mouse on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this by `plotoptions`

```
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: { 
            enabled: true, 
          inside: false,
          overflow: 'none',
          crop: true,
          shape: 'callout',
          backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.8)',
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
          borderWidth: .5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          y: -10,
          style: {
            fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            textShadow: 'none'
          },
          formatter: function() {
            return '<strong>'+this.series.name+'</strong>'
                        +'<br/>Group: <strong>'+ this.x+'</strong>'
                  +'<br/>Value: <strong>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)+'</strong>';
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

check this below example

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
     tooltip: {
     enabled: false,
      crosshairs: true
    },
      plotOptions: {
      series: {
       dataLabels: { 
         enabled: true, 
          inside: false,
          overflow: 'none',
          crop: true,
          shape: 'callout',
          backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.8)',
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
          borderWidth: .5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          y: -10,
          style: {
           fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
           fontSize: '10px',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            textShadow: 'none'
          },
          formatter: function() {
           return '<strong>'+this.series.name+'</strong>'
               +'<br/>Group: <strong>'+ this.x+'</strong>'
                  +'<br/>Value: <strong>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)+'</strong>';
          }
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tooltips, you can use the data labels:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/njp418tv/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels